# Android: Add neon glow effect to button

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-button, android-shapedrawable

I want to have a glow effect on button (in android studio) as shown in image:

[image: Button design image]

I didn't want an image for the background, so to get this effect, I have tried to do in xml file. I have added a stroke for the button and provide a shadow to the button (with same color as stroke).

I have used a linear gradient with 90 degree angle with start and end color same as the stroke, center color same as background color. Please see the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp" android:top="0dp">
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="50dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="45"
                    android:startColor="#8008c3fa"
                    android:endColor="#8008c3fa"
                    android:type="linear"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="5dp">
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
                <corners
                    android:radius="50dp"
                    />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="90"
                    android:centerX="50%"
                    android:centerColor="@color/trans_parent"
                    android:startColor="#8008c3fa"
                    android:endColor="#8008c3fa"
                    android:type="linear"
                    />
                <padding
                    android:left="0dp"
                    android:top="0dp"
                    android:right="0dp"
                    android:bottom="0dp"
                    />
                <size
                    android:width="270dp"
                    android:height="60dp"
                    />
                <stroke
                    android:width="2.5dp"
                    android:color="#08c3fa"
                    />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

</selector>
```

For the above xml, I got the below result:

[image: Result image from code]

Though the design and the result images look totally different, I think if we increase the center color height and keep a fadeout effect to the shadow, it can work. But I'm not able to do the same.

Comment: you can design one by using Figma or Adobe XD, and use the asset as a button

Comment: @Ali, thanks for the reply. But can't we do it using xml itself?

Comment: I haven't tried such level of gradients in android, So to be honest I really dont know if its possile

Comment: I haven't tried such level of gradients in android, So to be honest I really dont know if its possile

Answer (score 8):

I know it has been a while but if anyone is still interested in this effect, here is a custom view library I made which was inspired by this question:

[Glowing and Neon Button](https://github.com/SMehranB/GlowNeonButton)

[image]

It also has animated disable and enable methods as seen in the photo.

It's MIT Licensed, so do whatever you want with it. hope this helps someone.

Comment: how we can we keep animating the glow ?

Comment: @ZeeshanAli You can't. this is the animation for enabling/disabling the button.

Answer (score 5):

you can increase the center color height and keep a fadeout effect to the shadow by adding a nother item to the layer-list.
The first item makes the gradient for the upper bound, the rest is transparent and the second item makes the gradient for the lower bound the same way.

I added two more items to fill the left and the right semicircle.
I changed a few colours to enhance the effect but didnt trie too long, i think one could do alot more with more items and better colours :)

Cheers, Josh

the final result:

[image: final button]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="5dp" android:top="0dp">
                <shape>
                    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
                    <gradient
                        android:centerX="70%"
                        android:startColor="#804CD6FF"
                        android:centerColor="#8004485C"
                        android:endColor="#804CD6FF"
                        android:type="linear"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <corners
                        android:radius="50dp"
                        />
                    <gradient
                        android:angle="90"
                        android:centerX="30%"
                        android:centerColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:startColor="#8008c3fa"
                        android:endColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:type="linear"
                        />
                    <size
                        android:width="270dp"
                        android:height="60dp"
                        />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="2.5dp"
                        android:color="#08c3fa"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <corners
                        android:radius="50dp"
                        />

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="90"
                        android:centerX="70%"
                        android:centerColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:startColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:endColor="#8008c3fa"
                        android:type="linear"
                        />

                    <size
                        android:width="270dp"
                        android:height="60dp"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- the glow for the half circles, possible with radius as well. I liked
                 android:type="sweep" better because radius tends to fade out.-->
            <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <corners
                        android:radius="50dp"
                        />

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="360"
                        android:centerX="5%"
                        android:centerColor="#8008c3fa"
                        android:startColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:endColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:gradientRadius="360"
                        android:type="sweep"
                        />

                    <size
                        android:width="270dp"
                        android:height="60dp"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="6dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="5dp">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
                    <corners
                        android:radius="50dp"
                        />

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="360"
                        android:centerX="95%"
                        android:centerColor="@color/transparent"
                        android:startColor="#8008c3fa"
                        android:endColor="#8008c3fa"
                        android:gradientRadius="360"
                        android:type="sweep"
                        />

                    <size
                        android:width="270dp"
                        android:height="60dp"
                        />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have improved neon `Buttons` with a solid that has different `gradients` too. Take a look on this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68583069/how-to-put-shadow-with-gradient) I answered. I used the suggested library from "@Mehran B" and combined it with a custom `drawable` and a transparent `stroke` to make it more modifiable. As you can see in the samples below the `gradients` from the solids and shadows are separated and thus more flexible:

[image: Sample 1]

[image: Sample 2]